# All apps crash when opening files!

Tags: macos, catalina, crash

I've recently upgraded to Catalina (from El Capitan, which I've been using for years). It took me a while to realise, but *all apps crash when trying to open files!* I'd enormously appreciate anything I can try that might resolve this.

I can reproduce as follows:

1. Open any app (I've tried VS Code, TextEdit, Keynote, Preview, TexShop)
2. Select `File -> Open`

At this point I see a beachball and the app goes into a "not responding" state until I force-quit it.

I can create new files, and I can open files if they happen to be in the "open recent" menu, so I guess it's the file open dialog itself that's causing the problem.

Obviously this is a major issue for me, so help would be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: Open `Console` app (Applications > Utilities). Now open the files that crash the apps. Does Console print any errors or faults? Share it with us here.

Comment: @sfxedit console works fine, and there don't seem to be any problems with any files I've looked at. It's important to realise, it's not that there are specific files that are crashing my apps, it's that all apps are crashing at the moment of entering the file open dialog. The crash is before I can select a file to open it, not after.

Comment: I understood your issue - but usually when something like this happens, `Console` will show some Errors recorded in the logs which we can then use to determine what the issue is. There's a tab button on top of console called *Errors and Faults* to view it. (To clarify, I am asking you to keep `Console` open and open a file in the other apps that you listed, and wait for the app to hang / crash. Then check `Console` to see if it shows any errors.).

Comment: @sfxedit ah, I see. For now, I rebooted into internet recovery mode (hold Shift-Option-CMD-R while rebooting) and ran "first aid" on my startup disk in Disk Utility. Now I am able to open files, but I'm actually not sure if it was rebooting or fixing the permissions that changed it. If it starts happening again I will try that. Sorry for not understanding your previous comment.

Comment: (On the other hand, if it keeps working for another week or so, I'll post a self-answer.)

Comment: I've faced this kind of issue - randomly Finder and Spotlight would freeze. In my case it was both issues with the partition Volume that needed to be repaired and file permission issues.

Comment: @sfxedit although this problem hasn't come back, I now have another one that might be another manifestation of the same issue. I've posted it separately [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/410816/chrome-and-safari-crashing-constantly), along with details of the console output. (I am happy to give more details if you can give me pointers on which messages might be relevant - there are loads of them and I can't find a way to copy them all at once.)